# How to show user entered EditText value in a android dialogue box

Tags: java, android

my modified sample of my work basically below  i have 2 editboxes i want the values of the both to be shown in an alertbox, rest of the code works fine, the alertbox does show up but without the entered values.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    EditText username = null;
    EditText password = null;
    Button login;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        EditText usern = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        String usernm = usern.getText().toString();
        String passnm = pass.getText().toString();
        final Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("SHOW FIELDS")
            .setMessage("USERNAME:" + usernm + "  PASSWORD:" + passnm)
            .setNegativeButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                    // do nothing
                    closeContextMenu();
                }
             });
         login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 alert.show();
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to get EditText's value on button so show  in AlertDialog as :

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          usernm = usern.getText().toString();
          passnm = pass.getText().toString();
             alert.show();
         }
```

and declare both `usernm` and `passnm` at class level

**EDIT :**
or best way create a method to show alert and call it on button click  as:

```
  public void showalert(){
          usernm = usern.getText().toString();
          passnm = pass.getText().toString();
          alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this)
            .setTitle("SHOW FIELDS")
            .setMessage("USERNAME:" + usernm + "  PASSWORD:" + passnm)
            .setNegativeButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                    // do nothing
                    closeContextMenu();
                }
             });
     alert.show();
    }
```

and call this method on button click as:

```
 login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        showalert();
     }:
 });
```

and declare all variables at class level by which you can access it in whole class as :

```
public class Main extends Activity {
EditText usern ;
EditText pass ;
Button login;

String usernm ,passnm; //<<< Declare here
Builder alert;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     usern = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
     pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
     login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

         login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
              showalert();
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: @user1910290  : declare both `String usernm` and `String passnm` at class level means before `onCreate` then you will able to access these variables in whole class